# fragment is not replaced on click

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am developing an app in which i have detail activity which consist a detail fragment ,a detail fragment contain a 4 button and what i want when i clicked on that button i ll move to the new fragment but my fragment is not replacing as i used the fragment Transaction replace method ,pleaase provide me the better approach and  look forward to mine approach as well

this is detail fragment

```
public class DetailActivityFragment extends Fragment{

TextView textView;
ImageView imageView;
TextView details;
Button button;
public DetailActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);


   Bundle getBundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();

    String name = getBundle.getString("NAME");
    textView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bioname);
    textView.setText(name);
    imageView= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(getBundle.getInt("IMAGE"));
    Log.v("test", "images are coming");
     button= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_quickfacts);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = new QuickFacts();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            Log.v("replace","fragment repalacd");
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}

fragment detail.xml

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context="com.example.rahul.famousbiography.DetailActivityFragment"
   tools:showIn="@layout/activity_detail"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bioname"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#141715"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bioname" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_quickfacts"

    android:text="Quick Facts"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp"

    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/quick_facts"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/biodetail"

    android:text="Biography"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp"

    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/quick_facts"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/exit"

    android:text="Exit"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp"

    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/quick_facts"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/quotes"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/biodetail"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/quotes"

    android:text="Quotes"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp"

    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/quick_facts"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_quickfacts"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

quick facts fragment class which is going to be replaced through o click

```
 public class QuickFacts extends Fragment {
TextView detailText;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
          View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quick_facts, container, false);
          Bundle getBundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
           String details=getBundle.getString("DETAIL");
           detailText= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_add);
           detailText.setText(details);

           return view;
}
```

}
my hosted activity

```
     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"

         />

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_detail" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post your hosting activity xml and java code as well?

Comment: where is your R.id.container_body?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906966/using-button-to-change-layout-using-fragment/26907089#26907089

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not correct becoause you use this code in your fragment. if you have onClick in your fragment, must connect activity to your fragment. you can make an interface and implements in your activity. you can use these codes:

your Interface Class:

```
public interface IViewClickDetailQuick {
    public void onClickFragmentDetail();
    public void onClickFragmentQuick();
}
```

in your fragment class add these methods:

```
private IViewClickDetailQuick mListener;

 @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener =
                    (IViewClickDetailQuick)  activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement  IViewClickDetailQuick");
        }
    }

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
```

add this code in your onClick method implementation in fragment:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           mListener.onClickFragmentQuick();
        }
    });
```

in your activity class you must implements IViewClickDetailQuick interface and add your code there, like this:

```
 @Override
    public void onClickFragmentDetail() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClickFragmentQuick() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new QuickFacts()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
Fragment frag= new QuickFacts();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, frag);
// when back button pressed come back to this Fragment...
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```